# RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time .. with retain_graph = True

Tags: python, pytorch

I use the following model:

```
class DeepGraphInfomax(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, hidden_channels, pos_summary, summary):#, encoder):#, , corruption):
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden_channels = hidden_channels
        self.pos_summary = pos_summary
        self.summary = summary

        self.weight = Parameter(torch.Tensor(hidden_channels, hidden_channels))


    def loss(self, pos_z, neg_z, summary):
        r"""Computes the mutual information maximization objective."""
        pos_loss = -torch.log(
            self.discriminate(pos_z, summary, sigmoid=True) + EPS).mean()
        neg_loss = -torch.log(1 -
                              self.discriminate(neg_z, summary, sigmoid=True) +
                              EPS).mean()

        return pos_loss + neg_loss
```

and run my loss function with:

```
def train():
    model.train()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    #pos_z, neg_z, summary = model(data.x, data.edge_index)
    loss = model.loss(embedding_pos, embedding_neg, result)
    loss.backward(retain_graph = True)
    optimizer.step()
    return loss.item()
```

which result in the following error even though I used retain_graph = True

```
RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved tensors after calling backward.
```

Comment: can you provide the full body of the error. does the  backward in model.train() also retain the graph?

Comment: The train() method does not belong to the class and I guess you have another train method that belong to the DeepGraphInfomax. The error might be at the backward of class method train(self) where you dont retain the graph. one remedy could be to put the `model.train()` at the end before the return (if you do one iteration) if not and if you dont update the data, you have to add retain_graph to class method train. Having two train methods doesnt make sense from here but anyways.

Comment: I don't have a train method in my DeepGraphInfomax class (I did not define one). When I put     loss.backward(retain_graph = True) after optimizer.step() the following error occurs: RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [128, 128]] is at version 1; expected version 0 instead. Hint: enable anomaly detection to find the operation that failed to compute its gradient, with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True).